# Standard way to serialize and plot IP addresses?

Tags: python, ip, data-visualization, data-science

I am trying to find a way to convert IP addresses to integers or real values so they can be mathematically grouped and plotted in a meaningful way. Ideally IPs with the same leftmost octet would be similar, IPs sharing the leftmost two octets would be more similar, and so on.

Is there a standard, accepted way to do this? Codified in, say, a Python library? Or am I just going to have to cook up my own algorithm?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean, like... the [`ipaddress` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)?

```
>>> import ipaddress
>>> i = ipaddress.ip_address('10.9.8.7')
>>> int(i)
168364039
```

IP addresses with the same leftmost octet will be close, because if you convert an address to int, it just refers to the actual number an IP address represents (10.9.8.7 ≙ 10*256^3 + 9*256^2 + 8*256^1 + 7*256^0).

It also works for IPv6:

```
>>> int(ipaddress.ip_address("2001:db8::1"))
42540766411282592856903984951653826561
```

Comment: I had thought about this, but in practice this module generates numbers significantly different from one another that really should be grouped together. e.g. 10.255.35.2 == 184493058 and 10.1.1.2 == 167837954. This translation is a bit more noisy than I'd ideally like, but maybe it will have to do.

Comment: It will still be pretty close, as you see. If you want to check whether, for example, the first octet matches, you can shift both values 24 to the right, i.e. `184493058>>24 == 167837954>>24`.